# How to get current authenticated user id using Vuejs and Django Rest...?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am using Vuejs as my frontend and I would simply like to get the current logged in user's id from Django Rest and display it. How would I do this?

serializer

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):



 class Meta:
     model = Customer
     fields = '__all__'
```

view

```
class CustomerRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer


class CustomerUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateCustomerSerializer
    permission_class = permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly


class CustomerCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CreateCustomerSerializer


class CustomerListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
```

url

```
path('customers/<int:pk>', views.CustomerRetrieveView.as_view()),
    path('customers/update/<int:pk>', views.CustomerUpdateView.as_view()),
    path('customers/all', views.CustomerListView.as_view()),
    path('customers/new', views.CustomerCreateView.as_view()),
```

script vue

```
update(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     this.axios
    .post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/customers/new`, {'user': **???**, 'phone': this.phone })
    .then(response => {console.log(response) ;this.$router.push('/') })
    .catch(err => { console.error(err) })
   }
```

Comment: you can store the JWT token after user logged in, and store it either on cookies and caches on your fronted part. that's it.  In your backend part, while user is try to do something on that time you can put check validation for e.g is_authenticated or not.

Comment: if you still getting stocked then feel free to contact with my skype: live:.cid.7143e40b271722c1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach that would work for all authentication methods is to create a small
`APIView` that simply returns the ID of the current user: `request.user.id`. Your frontend would make a GET request for this view.

Comment: can you help me pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65601221/vue-js-django-rest-framework-with-jwt-user-authentication-getting-anonymous-use